# use become() from Java

Tags: java, akka

I'm using Akka from Java. According to documentation, *`context.become()`* takes `Procedure<Object>` as a parameter. In fact, it expects *`PartialFunction<Object, BoxedUnit>`* which appears to be something auto-generated with lot's of methods with strange names.

What is the right way of using *become()* from Java?

PS
  i'm using Akka 2.0.3

Update:
Looks like that there are two methods: context() and getContext(). The first one returns ActorContext, and the second one returns UntypedActorContext. UntypedActorContext has `become(Procedure<Object>)`.

Comment: I don't understand why people downvote without mentioning why.

Comment: @MarounMaroun maybe, they are upset to see, that the documentation does not match reality? :)

Comment: Why not paste a link to the documentation where you are seeing this? And also state what class "context" is

Comment: I'm talking about ActorContext. Here is the place in documentation:
http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/2.0.3/java/untyped-actors.html#Upgrade

Comment: In the generated API documentation, become() has different signature:
http://doc.akka.io/api/akka/2.0.3/#akka.actor.ActorContext

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You are confusing Akka Java and Scala API. Technically you can use Scala libraries like Akka from Java code, but quite often it's verbose and cumbersome. So the Akka team decided to develop to separate APIs - native in Scala and Java adapter.

In Scala API you extend [`akka.actor.Actor`](http://doc.akka.io/api/akka/2.0.3/akka/actor/Actor.html) which has a `context` field of type [`akka.actor.ActorContext`](http://doc.akka.io/api/akka/2.0.3/akka/actor/ActorContext.html). This `ActorContext.become()` accepts [`PartialFunction`](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/index.html#scala.PartialFunction), which is a Scala-specific class.

On the other hand in Java API you extend [`akka.actor.UntypedActor`](http://doc.akka.io/api/akka/2.0.3/akka/actor/UntypedActor.html) having (Java-like) method `getContext()`, returning [`akka.actor.UntypedActorContext`](http://doc.akka.io/api/akka/2.0.3/akka/actor/UntypedActorContext.html). This one accepts [`akka.japi.Procedure`](http://doc.akka.io/api/akka/2.0.3/akka/japi/Procedure.html).

To cut the long story short - if you are using Java API, stick to it. There is a clear distinction between Scala and Java documentation.

Comment: i understand it, in general. but is there a formal method to identify what belongs to Java and what to Scala API? both context() and getContext() are technically available from Java, so it's hard to guess what should be used.

Comment: @aav: ScalaDoc + naming convention for starters. `context()` is Scala-like name while `getContext()` is typical to Java. It's also documented well.

Answer (score 0):

There are lot of good examples on how to do this in java as well.Hopefully this sample helps :

```
Procedure<Object> angry = new Procedure<Object>() {
@Override
public void apply(Object message) {
  if (message.equals("bar")) {
    getSender().tell("I am already angry?", getSelf());
  } else if (message.equals("foo")) {
    getContext().become(happy);
  }
}
};

Procedure<Object> happy = new Procedure<Object>() {
@Override
public void apply(Object message) {
  if (message.equals("bar")) {
    getSender().tell("I am already happy :-)", getSelf());
  } else if (message.equals("foo")) {
    getContext().become(angry);
  }
 }
};

public void onReceive(Object message) {
if (message.equals("bar")) {
  getContext().become(angry);
} else if (message.equals("foo")) {
  getContext().become(happy);
} else {
  unhandled(message);
}
```

}
}

Answer (score 0):

In short, when using `Java API`, make sure you are calling `getContext()` method instead of `context()` which is intended to be used with `Scala API`.

Checkout [this (java)](https://github.com/daggerok/sbt-examples/blob/master/akka-scala-vs-java/java/hello/src/main/java/com/github/daggerok/akka/quickstart/AkkaQuickStart.java#L38)

```
@Slf4j
@RequiredArgsConstructor
public class Greeter extends AbstractActor {

    private final ActorRef printer;

    public static Props props(ActorRef printer) {
        return Props.create(Greeter.class, printer);
    }

    @Override
    public Receive createReceive() {
        return withWhomToGreet(""); // initial state
    }

    private Receive withWhomToGreet(String name) {
        return receiveBuilder()
                .match(WhoToGreet.class, // changing actor state context
                       whoToGreet -> getContext().become(withWhomToGreet(whoToGreet.getWho())))
                .match(Greet.class, greet -> {
                    String msg = format("Hola, %s", name);
                    log.info("sending {} to {}", msg, printer);
                    printer.tell(Greeting.of(msg), self());
                })
                .matchAny(o -> {
                    log.error("unexpected: {}", o);
                    unhandled(o);
                })
                .build();
    }
}
```

or [this (kotlin)](https://github.com/daggerok/akka-kotlin-example/blob/master/src/main/kotlin/com/github/daggerok/akkakotlinexample/Counter.kt#L26)

```
class CounterActor : AbstractActor() {

    companion object Factory {
        sealed class Commands {
            override fun toString(): String = javaClass.simpleName

            object Increment : Commands()
            object Decrement : Commands()
            object GetState : Commands()
        }

        private val type = CounterActor::class.java
        val props: Props = Props.create(type) { CounterActor() }
        val name: String = type.simpleName
    }

    override fun createReceive(): Receive = withCounter(0) // init state

    private fun withCounter(counter: Int): Receive =
        receiveBuilder()
            .matchAny { cmd ->
                context.system.log().info("current: $counter, received: $cmd")
                when (cmd) {
                    is GetState -> sender.tell("counter value: $counter", self)
                    is Increment -> {
                        // switch context with new updated actor state,
                        // actor is still stateless, similarly like we
                        // doing in scala for context.become 
                        // Make sure with Java API you are calling
                        // getContext() method, not context()!
                        context.become(withCounter(counter + 1))
                    }
                    is Decrement -> // another change of actor state
                        context.become(withCounter(counter - 1))
                    else -> unhandled(cmd)
                }
            }
            .build()
}
```

Everything could be done with same idea like it's done in Scala